# disable knex oracledb autocommit

Tags: node.js, oracle, knex.js

i have used knex with oracledb client with the next config

```
const database = knex({
  client: "oracledb",
  connection: {
    user: DB_USER,
    password: DB_PASS,
    host: DB_HOST,
    port: DB_PORT,
    database: DB_NAME,
  },
  debug: DEBUG_MODE,
  fetchAsString: ["number", "clob"],
});
```

**when execute any query it's auto committed and i want to disable it !**

```
database("EMPLOYEES")
 .where({ EMPLOYEE_ID: 100 })
 .update({ EMAIL: "hi@example.com" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Click [here to see the original reply](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/4445)!

```
To prevent autocommit you need to start transaction and run queries that should not be autocommitted there. If you disable autocommit you will not have any idea in what state each db session created by pool is.

Though if you don’t care what result you may get or use just a single connection in that special case disabling autocommit could work. In that case it probably can be set with knex.raw().
```

Comment: Yep. Disabling it will not work with knex. You need to use transactions instead.